# Unnecessarily body unload get fired on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to abandon session on browser close event in my asp.net project .
I used javascript body unload event with ajax call to do this and it works fine .
But on browser refresh , body unload event get fired and user session is lost .

How can i over come this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't.

There are some hacks that could allow you to do it, but it's not going to be perfect and it's not really a solution worth the hassle.

Perhaps rethink why you actually want this to happen?

Comment: Thanks for your answer , can you please provide some links or hints to " hacks that could allow you to do it "

Comment: Something like checking if the user has pressed the F5 key... I've even seen some people check mouse location to see if it goes to the X of a browser... But like I said, it's not really a solution that will work in all instances so not really worth it.  Let me know why you need this to happen and perhaps we can come up with an alternative solution